# Green tint color shift converting RGBA to YUV420p ffmpeg libavcodec

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, yuv, libavcodec

I was wondering someone could help. I'm currently taking converting RBGA bitmaps to YUV420p before encoding the frames with h264 codec and dumping the encoded packets to file successfully.

I'm also able to playback the h264 video file in VLC. However, there seems to be a color shift which is more apparent where grey is actually light tint of screen. I'm used a an animation video as my example which is supposed to show a blue sky in the background, however after converting the image, I'm getting an orange sky background. Do you have any ideas how I can fix this please?

Do you happen to know if it's possible to convert rgba to yuv BEFORE calling sws_scale and before encoding packet?

Comment: Apologies the problem is light tint of screen appears throughout the video

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers. If you missed something in your question edit it to include that part also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong pixel format.

I should of been using BGR24, but I was using RGBA. I realized this after looking as the how I was decoding the frame to bitmap originally and it was decoded as BGR24

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the specify the `stride`?
Or used a wrong color format? (BGRA, RGB, etc.)

Comment: I found out the problem. I was using the wrong pixel format. I was using RGBA when I should of been using BGR24.